# Solution to a path problem with maximum values of derivatives

Tags: derivatives

I want to minimize the travel time from known position A to  known position B while the derivatives of path are below their maximum value.

I have:

`v[t] <= vmax` ... velocity

`a[t] <= amax` ... acceleration

`j[t] <= jmax` ... jerk

`j2[t] <= j2max` ... jounce

`j2[t]` is -j2max or 0 or j2max

This is the plot of all values:

[image: path derivatives]

I would need to find a method that works well on lots of path segments. I was thinking of some finite difference method or something similar. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you care how fast you're moving when you get there?

Comment: I have a limit velocity for every segment. So the final velocity has to be less than the max velocity for the next segment.